# How to disable dragging wx.DIalog from the user

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I want disable dragging the wx.Dialog. I noticed when I remove the caption the user can not drag the dialog, but I want to keep the caption. Any suggestions would be helpful? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to remove the caption as you've already found. You might be able to use a wx.Timer or catch a dragging event of some sort and center the dialog that way, but otherwise, removing the caption is the way to go.